# Converting from QML to SLD on the command line

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, style, sld, qml

We have the problem of automating the conversion of MapInfo TAB styles to SLD. I've managed to achieve the first part of the process (TAB -> QML) using this tool:

https://github.com/NathanW2/MapInfo-to-QGIS-style-generator

I can load the resulting QML file into QGIS and export it as SLD manually. However, would I really need is a way of doing this via the command line.

Is this possible with QGIS, or does anyone know another tools that might help here?

Comment: You can write scripts for QGIS in Python which might be an option (I'm not a QGIS user so not 100% sure whether what you want is possible). If so, you could call your python script from the command line to do the conversion.