# Batch convert of viewer styles from QML to SLD

Tags: qgis, geoserver, sld, batch, qml

Until now I was saving styles in QML files. 
Now I need them in SLD to be used in GeoServer.
Is there a way how to perform a batch convert?

Comment: Related (but unanswered): https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187971/converting-from-qml-to-sld-on-the-command-line?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK In this moment (qgis 3.6) you can't without writing some simple python code.... but I could be wrong.
May I suggest to do a feature request in QGIS (better offering work to a core dev or hoping someone will dev for you)? adding a processing algorithm doing sld export is simple and than use it in batch.